# Do Flurry Ads from AppSpot work in the Xcode simulator or just on the device

Tags: flurry

I'm about to start working with Flurry, can I expect the ads to display in the simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can - check out http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/Code for integration instructions.

No special setup is required to see ads render in the simulator vs on a device.

Answer (score 0):

I recently integrated it into our project and I can confirm to you that the ads do indeed show up in the simulator. However I had only the 5.1 Simulator available when developing and noticed issues with a device which had iOS 4 installed on it. Below iOS 5, Flurry Appspot might not be supported...